# How to filter the string data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

I have a data in a string which I need to further filter the data save it in another string  variable.using jQuery.

For example, I have

```
 var str= 'a="apple",a="ajax",b="boy",b="bird",b="ball".........';
```

rom this I want data where a=" ", so apple,ajaxneed to be saved

The following data is returned from web service as string format:

> <?xml
>   version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><TermStore><T
>   a9="5af46de3-630b-4cd9-aff3-4d1fbb95333c" a21="false"
>   a61="0"><LS><TL a32="SharePoint" a31="true" /><TL
>   a32="MOSS" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint 2007" a31="false"
>   /><TL a32="SharePoint 2010" a31="false" /><TL
>   a32="SharePoint 2013" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint Admin"
>   a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint Designer" a31="false"
>   /><TL a32="SharePoint Developer" a31="false" /><TL
>   a32="SharePoint Infopath" a31="false" /><TL a32="WSS"
>   a31="false" /></LS><DS><TD a11="It is an extensible
>   web based Platfrom" /></DS><TMS><TM
>   a24="f03e532e-6e71-48c4-b499-c93efc7a4f7b" a12="Microsoft" a40=""
>   a17="true"
>   /></TMS></T></TermStore>`

from this I need to filter only `a32=""`, values and store it in different string.

Comment: Have you even attempted to solve this yourself? I can think of a 3 line algo that could do this for you, but why should I bother solving your problem, if you haven't tried to solve it yourself first?

Comment: Please find now exact data now tell me How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

out of the top of my head this should get the job done

```
var get='a';
var split = str.split(",");
var final = '';
for(var i in split)
{
    split2 = split[i].split("=");
    if(split2[0] == get)
        final += split[i]+','
}
var str2 = final.substring(0,final.length-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but when I try to display str2 in alert(). it returns following error  when "Prevent this page from creating addition dialogs "   please help

Comment: It works fine here. That error you're mentioning seams to be Chromes usual warning  when a page is displaying multiple alerts

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'a="apple",a="ajax",b="boy",b="bird",b="ball"';

function filterIt(str){
   var filtered = [];
   str.replace(/a="(.*?)"/g, function(a, b){
       filtered.push(b);
   });
   return filtered.join(",");
}

filterIt(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at jquery parsexml
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Based on its documentaion it should be

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><TermStore><T a9="5af46de3-630b-4cd9-aff3-4d1fbb95333c" a21="false" a61="0"><LS><TL a32="SharePoint" a31="true" /><TL a32="MOSS" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint 2007" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint 2010" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint 2013" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint Admin" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint Designer" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint Developer" a31="false" /><TL a32="SharePoint Infopath" a31="false" /><TL a32="WSS" a31="false" /></LS><DS><TD a11="It is an extensible web based Platfrom" /></DS><TMS><TM a24="f03e532e-6e71-48c4-b499-c93efc7a4f7b" a12="Microsoft" a40="" a17="true" /></TMS></T></TermStore>';
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
var a32="";
$title = $xml.find( "[a32]" ).each(function(){
a+=$(this).attr('a32');
});
```